# RabbitMQ an option to use for caching with Sites 9 instead of ActiveMQ?

Tags: sites-9, cache

In Tridion Sites 9 we have the option to use a JMS Broker to help cache objects in Content Delivery.

If any JMS Broker can work, would it be possible to use RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Scaling out the deployer: ActiveMQ and Amazon SQS are supported.
>
> For server side caching JMS is supported but the JMS vendor is not specified as it does not matter, just the type of messages.

Here's a link Robert: https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000007093

That articles quotes the documentation (8.5): https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-7E728735-073B-4827-AABE-B45592CFF36D ... and

the Sites 9 version is here (same bar reference to marketing title and a couple of JAR references): https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-7E728735-073B-4827-AABE-B45592CFF36D